# Illegal start of expression when reading file

Tags: java, netbeans, bufferedreader

I am getting an error in the  String readFileIntoString(String path) as illegal start of expression can someone tell me what to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

//public class PreProcess {

    // Read a file into a string. Takes file path, returns string

    /**
     *
     * @param path
     * @return
     */
    public String readFileIntoString(String path) {
        char[] line = new char[1024];
        StringBuilder dataString;
        dataString = new StringBuilder(5000);

        try {
            try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
                while (true) {
                    int readLength = input.read(line);
                    if (readLength == -1)
                        break;
                    dataString.append(line, 0, readLength);
                }
            }
            return dataString.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            return " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really take some time to properly format your postings; also, learn to use punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

method inside method is considered as `illegal start of expression`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    public String readFileIntoString(String path) {
    }
}
```

move

```
    public String readFileIntoString(String path) {}
```

to out side of `main()`

Answer (score 1):

1. The method should be outside `main()`.
2. You need to have a catch{} block or a finally{} block after the inner try{}

`try{}` blocks should always be followed by `catch{}` or `finally{}`